# Check the Version of an Enqueue'd External Library

Tags: plugin-development

I want to use an external font library in my plugin, but I want to do a version check first to determine if I should bother enqueue'ing my version or not. I know I can see if a library is already loaded -- `wp_script_is()` -- but I don't know how to check the library's version. Any ideas?

```
    if ( wp_script_is() || wp_script_is( 'registered' ) ) {
        \\ version check here
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a nice way of doing it though wp_script_*, but you can go to the global directly:

```
global $wp_scripts;
$version = $wp_scripts->query( 'jquery' )->ver;
```

Here the `query` returns the script's [`_WP_Dependency` object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/_WP_Dependency), and then we can get the version from it. (Annoyingly `wp_script_is( ..., 'registered' )` fetches the `_WP_Dependency` but then casts the result to a bool to return.)

This only works for registered scripts; apologies I don't know the distinction, but AFAICS a script can only be queued if it's registered, and it's only the registered data that holds the version.